# Windows ::CopyFile generates error code 127 - "The specified procedure could not be found"

Tags: windows, visual-c++, runtime, kernel32

What can be the reason of error while calling `::CopyFile(dir1, dir2, false)`. 
`GetLastError()` returns value 127 what in my opinion means that kernel32.dll was found but it doesn't contain `::CopyFile`method or any other method that is called in `::CopyFile`. What can be the reason of such behavior?

**Update 1**

Can this error be connected with dll loading (I don't know if it is possible but maybe some dll is not loaded in the memory or something like that happens)? Because I wonder how it is possible that on the same machine test program calling the same API works and main exe has problem with `::CopyFile` and `copy_file`

**Update 2**

Can it be caused by some external program such as a virus scanner, malware scanner, or other program is running in the background opening files.

**Update 3**

On other PC the same function returns error 1285. Only on 2 PCs this problem is reproducible.

Comment: Does your call to `GetLastError()` immediately follows `::CopyFile(dir1, dir2, false)`?

Comment: Most likely cause: you called `GetLastError` without first checking the return value from `CopyFile`.

Comment: I check the `GetLastError()` in situation when `::CopyFile` returns false

Comment: @VladFeinstein yes I call it immediately after if statement returns `false`

Comment: Break after the copy and type '$err,hr' at a watch pane, to decipher the error message:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164891.aspx

Comment: @Ofek Shilon - it is `@err`, not `$err`. However, it will return the same error code as `GetLastError()`. Of course, with description, as you specified the format as `hr`, but @patmar already knows what that error means.

Comment: @VladFeinstein, the @ prefix is considered legacy and $ is encouraged (see my link).

Comment: @patmar:  Can you check $err,hr just *before* the CopyFile, to verify that it's different from 127?  LastError can often contain leftovers from previous operations.

Comment: @OfekShilon i cannot check this result using break point because i cannot reporduce this error it is read from users log on only one of the computers

Comment: From code what I can see that there is almost no possibility to set this error before. I could miss something but all conditions are in my opininion checked correcty. And documentation says `Retrieves the calling thread's last-error code value. The last-error code is maintained on a per-thread basis. Multiple threads do not overwrite each other's last-error code.`

Comment: Many OS operations internally fill LastError, and few bother to clean them up. It might be a good idea to log LastError just before the copy.     If you can't reproduce the problem locally, can you try to pin it down? Perhaps you can call CopyFile somewhere earlier, copying a surely existent and accessible file onto itself?

Comment: @OfekShilon I will try to reproduce this problem with addiational log before `::CopyFile method`. But it seems strange that `::CopyFile` returns false and doesn't set error code. Documentation says that in such situation error should be set.

Comment: You're probably right. What about calling a 'toy' CopyFile just to see that it isn't a problem with file existence/accessibility?

Comment: @OfekShilon I've already created such test tool that tests few copy functions. I will let you know when I find something

Comment: After running test application on user computer I can say that `CopyFile` method works correctly. There is only problem with my application where it generates 127 error